Are tag badges created automatically?
The reason I ask is because we now have 100 mining questions but the wording of descriptions on tag badges is vague.
Per this answer:
What are tag badges? How do they work?
A tag must appear on a minimum of 100 questions to be considered for tag badges.
To be considered implies it isn't automatic.  We have 100 mining questions (our first 100+ tag) but no tag badge.  Does the badge need to be created manually, will it happen automatically, or is there some bug preventing its creation?

The badge is created automatically. However, all requirements must be met, and we don't check these at every hour. You don't need just the tag to have 100+, you also need someone eligible for the badge.
In this case, there is a user who is eligible for the bronze badge, with over 100 score across answers to over 20 non-wiki questions.
However, as the 100th instance of the tag has only shown up today, it will probably not be until the end of the day that the tag badge is awarded to David. It is typical to allow for at least 48 hours before any badge with complex requirements. Usually doesn't necessarily take that long, but it has been reported to take that long.

Looks like you are right.  The tag badge has shown up and David was the first to receive it.
